# How to read csv file and save the data in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, express

I am creating an REST API in **nodejs** 
where **I am trying to read the data from the csv file and 
trying to store the data to mongodb** and later trying to perform CRUD operations using csv file.

I am using Express framework

My Approach:

1. Call a method to read csv file.
2. create a array and add the rows into that array.
3. iterate the list to json(here I am struck).

**Please Help!!!!**

**I am new to NodeJS**

```
const express = require('express')
const app= express();

const parse = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');

//require('arrayList');
// var list= new arr.ArrayList;
var list= new Array();
fs.createReadStream('datasample.csv')
  .pipe(parse({delimiter: ':'}))
  .on('data', (row) => {
    list.push(row)
    console.log(row);
  })
   .on('end', () => {
     console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
     console.log(list)
     for (var i in list) {
       var str= list[i].toString()
       var res= str.split(",")
       //const post= new Post();

       console.log(res);
         //console.log(list[i]);
      }
  });
```

Schema which I am using

```
const mongoose= require("mongoose");
const employeeSchema= mongoose.Schema(
    {
        employee_id:{

            type: Number,
            required: true
        } ,

        employee_name:String
    }
)
module.exports= mongoose.model("Post",employeeSchema)
```

Comment: Have you created the schema for the same ? \

Comment: yes i created employee schema

Comment: How you want to store the data ? I mean in which field, which manner ?

Comment: in csv I will be having two columns- employeeid and employee name respectively
Accordingly I will process the csv and store the column values to the db i.e mongo

Comment: okay, got your question. Firstly you need to create a json object from the csv. Then you can use insertMany() method of mongodb and pass that json object to it.

Comment: So according to you firstly I use csvtojson package and then I  use the insertMany() method ????  Code solution will be very helpful. if you can provide

Comment: If you just want to import CSV, you can try using [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/). See the linked page for details on how to use the tool with CSV.

Comment: Yes @rajatgoyal1994

Comment: @kevinadi I am trying to read and save the data from csv not the file!!!! Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

You can find an approach of importing csv file data into mongodb from below link.

http://programmerblog.net/import-csv-file-using-nodejs/